# How to click on a ui-sref link in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor

```
<li ui-sref="settings.contacts" class="ng-scope active" ui-sref-active="active">
```

How would I select this element in protractor? I have tried to use element(by.partialLinkText but I'm getting undefined error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the ui-sref using [protractor-linkuisref-locator](https://www.npmjs.org/package/protractor-linkuisref-locator).

Answer (score 6):

If have another solution.

```
var link =  element(by.css('[ui-sref="settings.contacts"]'));
```

Works well.

Answer (score 0):

Click event not work

```
var link =  element(by.css('[ui-sref="settings.contacts"]'));
link.click();
```

It will through error,

```
Failed: unknown error: Element <button class="button button-clear button-stable link ng-binding" type="button" ui-sref="login" href="#/login">...</button> is not clickable at point (179, 559). Other element would receive the click: <div class="loading-container visible active">...</div>
```